# How can I fix my code to make it send the json data as a response to postman's GET requests?

Tags: node.js, express, http, request, postman

The data I am receiving through the code is outputting to the cmd through `console.log` but I can't seem to figure out how to make that same data available for `GET` requests from postman. Thank you

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;
const apicall = require('./apicall');
const request = require('request');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello world!")
    
});
   
app.get('/getinfo', (req, res, body) => {
    const getToken = (url, callback) => {
        const options = {
            url: process.env.GET_TOKEN,
            json: true,
            body: {
                client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
                grant_type: 'client_credentials'
            }
        };
    
        request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode}`)
            console.log(body);
    
            callback(res);
        });
    }
    
    var AT = '';
    var info = '';
    getToken(process.env.GET_TOKEN, (res) => {
        AT = res.body.access_token;
        return AT;
    });
    
    const getGames = (url, accessToken, callback) => {
        const gameOptions = {
            url: process.env.GET_GAMES,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Client-ID': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        };
    
        request.get(gameOptions, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            let x = '';
            console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode}`);
            console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            //res.send(parsed);
            //req.body.getinfo = JSON.parse(body);
        })
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
       getGames(process.env.GET_GAMES, AT, (response) => {
    
        });
    }, 1000);
    //res.send(JSON.parse(body));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: The Javascript code that you posted has syntax errors. Please correct them.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Sorry, corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just pipe it to the response like so `.pipe(res)`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;
const apicall = require('./apicall');
const request = require('request');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello world!")
    
});

app.get('/ne2', (req, res) => {
    //res.send('This is the new endpoint');
    apicall.getCall;
});
   
app.get('/getinfo', (req, res, body) => {
    const getToken = (url, callback) => {
        const options = {
            url: process.env.GET_TOKEN,
            json: true,
            body: {
                client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
                grant_type: 'client_credentials'
            }
        };
    
        request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode}`)
            console.log(body);
    
            callback(res);
        });
    }
    
    var AT = '';
    var info = '';
    getToken(process.env.GET_TOKEN, (res) => {
        AT = res.body.access_token;
        return AT;
    });
    
    const getGames = (url, accessToken, callback) => {
        const gameOptions = {
            url: process.env.GET_GAMES,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Client-ID': process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        };
    
        request.get(gameOptions, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            let x = '';
            console.log(`Status: ${res.statusCode}`);
            //console.log(JSON.parse(body));
            info = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(info);
            //res.send(parsed);
            //req.body.getinfo = JSON.parse(body);
        }).pipe(res);
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
       getGames(process.env.GET_GAMES, AT, (response) => {
    
        });
    }, 1000);
    //res.send(info);
    
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `res.send` in the callback of a `request.get`. But in that context, `res` is the *incoming* response from the API that you call, not the *outgoing* response created by your app. Only the *outgoing* response contains a `send` method.

To keep both separate, use different names:

```js
app.get("/getinfo", function(req, res) {
  request.get(..., function(err, incoming_res, body) {
    res.json(JSON.parse(body));
  });
});
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you're saying so far. So how can I send the response I get from the api to the postman through GET requests?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

`res.send` is a part of express. If the res.send that's failing is in `request.get` then that's because it's not a part of `express`.

From the docs for `request` it says that the response argument will be an instance of http.IncomingMessage. That should mean you can simply use `res.end`

Edit:

@HeikoTheißen is right. There is no `res.end`.

But this could be handled in a different way. If we can wrap the get request inside a promise, then we could resolve the promise with whatever needs to be sent from the get request.

An example:

```
const result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    request(gameOptions, function (error, response, body) {
         resolve ({status : 'A Ok!'}) // <--- send response here
    }
}
console.log ("result is ", result) // <-- Object {status : 'A Ok!'}
```

Comment: Hey guys, I've tried both solutions but I'm getting an error. First, the status is logging 'undefined' to the cmd and then : "Unexpected token u in JSON position 0"

Comment: I might just be writing something incorrectly, not sure tho.

Comment: If the `request.get` returns `body = undefined`, then you cannot parse it as JSON. The code I gave in my answer is just a skeleton and must be enriched with additional checks.

Comment: Zephyr, an `http.IncomingMessage` has no method `end`. Since it is incoming, you can only *read* it, but not *write* to it (like the `end` method does).

Comment: I'm going through the code trying to figure out the current syntax error I am getting, which is seemingly there even after resetting my code. After that, I'll have to look into how to fill up the skeleton code you have kindly proposed.

Comment: Okay, done with the bug. Do you have any pointers on how I should proceed?

Comment: Updated the comment after HeikoTheißen's comment. Not sure if you adjust your code this way but it could work.